# Prefill PDF form field in Docusign document before sending (transform_pdf_fields == true)

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign PHP SDK to create an envelope using a PDF with pre-existing form fields.

The fields are correctly being parsed by Docusign and show up on the resulting document.

However, I can't find a way to prefill some of those fields.

```
    // Create document model
    $document = new Document([
        'document_base64' => $base64_content,
        'name' => 'Document',
        'file_extensions' => 'pdf',
        'document_id' => 1, 'transform_pdf_fields' => true
    ]);

    $signer = new Signer([
        'email' => $args['client_email'],
        'name' => $args['client_name'],
        'recipient_id' => 1,
        'routing_order' => 1,
        'client_user_id' => $args['client_user_id']
    ]);

    // This is the attempt to prefill the fields
    // by using the same label as the PDF form.
    // But it does nothing.
    $text1 = new Text([
        'tab_label' => 'field_one', 'value' => $args['client_coverage'],
    ]);
    $text2 = new Text([
        'tab_label' => 'field_two', 'value' => $args['client_term'],
    ]);
    $signer->setTabs(new Tabs(['text_tabs' => [$text1, $text2]]));

    $definition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
        'email_subject' => "Please sign this document",
        'documents' => [$document],
        'recipients' => new Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]),
        'status' => 'sent',
    ]);
```

A call to the envelope tabs API shows the tabs in question with the exact tab label but the value is blank.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated! Thanks.

P.S. I can, after the envelope creation, get the document tabs, in order to get their IDs, and then make another request to update those.
So this is doable in 3 calls but I have a feeling that it should be possible to do in one - when the envelope is created initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sdragnev, this can work if you use composite templates

```
$inline_template = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\InlineTemplate([
    'recipients' => new Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]),  
    'sequence' => "1" 
    ]);
$inline_templates = [$inline_template];
$composite_template = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\CompositeTemplate([
    'composite_template_id' => "1",  
    'document' => $document,  
    'inline_templates' => $inline_templates
    ]);
$composite_templates = [$composite_template];
$envelope_definition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
    'composite_templates' => $composite_templates,  
    'email_subject' => "Agreement",  
    'status' => "sent" 
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks @IvanD, that did it!
The only wrinkle was that PDF form fields called "DocuSignSignHere" were no longer automatically recognized but manually adding the SignHere field to the signer worked fine.